# Why model.fit_generator() has Attribution Error?

Tags: python, keras

I am rerunning my kernel with an updated model. Previously the kernel works well, I've run for 6 times. But today this kernel throws the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-e6baca729854> in <module>
      1 # don't use hardcode video numbers
----> 2 pred = model.predict_generator(pred_gen, steps=len(filenames)//BATCH_SIZE)

...

    AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.ops.script_ops' has no attribute 'numpy_function'
```

Comment: did you update the tensorflow version?

Comment: I don't think we can say anything with a incomplete traceback and a vague description, something changed, and you are the only one that can tell us what.

Comment: @YOLO the current version of my code is 2.1.0. I run it on Kaggle.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I intended to post complete traceback but the post review said there was too much code. I guess I can try post without code blocks.

Comment: You can start by adding the complete traceback.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. When I ran the code again today, it ran well without error and the speed is quite fast. I guess it's something wrong with the network connection.